# Google Play Game Service

Tags: android

I am having an issue with Google Play Game Service where the leaderboard launches at random on launch and onresuming of the game from switching apps and selecting home. How can I change this behaviour?

```
if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(),
                RC_UNUSED);
public int gameMode;

public static void showLeaderboard(int mode) {
    me.gameMode = mode;
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (me.isSignedIn())
                me.onShowLeaderboard();
            else
                me.SignIn();
        }
    });
}

public static void submitScore(final int score) {
    me.gameMode = score / 1000000;
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            me.onSubmitScore(score % 1000000);
        }
    });

}


   public void onShowLeaderboard() {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(),
                RC_UNUSED);
    } else {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.signing_in));
        this.SignIn();
    }
}

public void onSubmitScore(int score) {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        switch (gameMode) {
        case 1:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard1),
                    score);
            break;
        case 2:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard2),
                    score);
            break;
        case 3:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard3),
                    score);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.signing_in));
        this.SignIn();
    }
}

boolean verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced() {
    final boolean CHECK_PKGNAME = true; // set to false to disable check
                                        // (not recommended!)

    // Did the developer forget to change the package name?
    if (CHECK_PKGNAME && getPackageName().startsWith("com.google.example.")) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "*** Sample setup problem: "
                        + "package name cannot be com.google.example.*. Use your own "
                        + "package name.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public void SignIn() {
    if (!verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced()) {
        showAlert("Sample not set up correctly. See README.");
        return;
    }

    // start the sign-in flow
    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    System.out.println("SignIn Failed!");
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    System.out.println("SignIn Successed!");
    onShowLeaderboard();
}
```

Comment: Anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because in your method 'onSignInSucceeded' you call 'onShowLeaderboard();' so everytime that the application is launched (first time or resumed) it will sign in and if the sign in process is successful then it will launch the method 'onShowLeaderboard();'

Answer (score 0):

For a specific leader board you should use:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(),
                YOUR_LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

instead of using:

```
startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(),
            RC_UNUSED);
```